# Copying a table into another table but preserving the same auto increment key

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a table A filled with records. I created a table B with same columns, and I want to copy all contents of A to B. However, table A has an auto incremented key, so if i had first three records (1,'itemA') (2,'itemB') (5,'itemE')  (assuming that 3,4,5 where deleted later). Those recors will be inserted into table B as (1,'itemA') (2,'itemB') (3,'itemE'). 
Is there a way to insert them exactly the same ?

Another thing is, table A is on mySql, and table B is on MS SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers above are good, but on MS SQL you can't insert auto increment value unless if you execute turn identiy_insert off:

> `SET IDENTITY_INSERT stock OFF;`
>
> `INSERT INTO stock ( stock_id,stock_item) VALUES (5,'itemE');`
>
> `SET IDENTITY_INSERT stock ON;`

This is EXCATLY what I was looking for. Thank you all :)

Comment: Before your `INSERT` statement you have to write:
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT stock ON;`

and after:

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT stock OFF;`

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK mysql allow inserting into auto_increment field, so you can use statement like

```
insert into table2 (id, name) select id, name from table1
```

but later, if you need insert into table values with generated auto_inc, you need set auto_increment in table2 with value of auto_inc of table1

```
alter table table2 AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = $dbName AND TABLE_NAME = 'table1')
```

Comment: I don't think you need to change the value of AUTO_INCREMENT, it will normally have a value of max(auto increment column) + 1. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a453/1

Comment: @Haz Typed right in browser, don't check in real, just for show idea. If you language is php you can store result of (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = $dbName AND TABLE_NAME = 'table1') into variable and then use it in ALTER TABLE

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand this is not completely right in general. If you want to continue with auto_inc field in second table like in first you must set same value. F.e. you insert in first table 10 rows then delete last 3 with you sugg. in first table next auto_inc will be 11 in second - 8. It's maybe ok, may be not.

Comment: Actually you don't need it only if you truncate your target table before, as truncating your table will automatically reset it's auto increment value to 0

Comment: @YassirKhaldi That's true, but only for TRUNCATE. So, it's not true for DELETE FROM for example

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

```
create table b like a;
insert into b select * from a;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a344a/1

Comment: thanks for your help.. this only works after you set IDENTITY_INSERT OFF

Answer (score 0):

At table with name test and columns (id autoinc, col1, col2, col3)
At table with name test2 and columns (id autoinc, col4, col5, col6)

```
INSERT INTO test(col4, col5, col6) SELECT col4, col5, col6 FROM test2;
```